# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field GrossPay

Tags: javascript, variables, static, non-static

For the calculation, Net Pay is calculated as the result from Gross Pay minus all deductions (Federal, State, Social Security, and Medicare). The number of hours per week will be used to compute Gross pay, Net pay, and Deductions.
You use the most appropriate data type for each variable.
public class NetPay {

```
double FEDERAL_TAX_PERCENT = 10.00; 
double STATE_TAX_PERCENT = 4.5;
double SOCIAL_SECURITY_PERCENT = 6.2;
double MEDICARE_PERCENT = 1.45;
double PAY_PER_HOUR = 7.25;

 int HoursPerWeek = 40;
 double GrossPay = PAY_PER_HOUR * HoursPerWeek;


 double Federal = GrossPay * FEDERAL_TAX_PERCENT / 100;
 double State = GrossPay * STATE_TAX_PERCENT / 100;
 double SocialSecurity= GrossPay * SOCIAL_SECURITY_PERCENT / 100;
 double Medicare = GrossPay * MEDICARE_PERCENT / 100;
 
 double NetPay = GrossPay - Federal - State - SocialSecurity - Medicare;
 



public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    
    System.out.println("Gross Pay:" + GrossPay); the question is come up here
    System.out.println("Net Pay:");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Deductions");
    System.out.println("Federal:");
    System.out.println("State:");
    System.out.println("Social Security:");
    System.out.println("Medicare:");

    
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

None of your variables are static so you can't reference them in your main function which is static. You could either declare all your variables in the main function, or declare them all as static. Or you could redesign your code a little bit and use an instance of your NetPay class. Also you labeled this as a javascript question, but thats Java.

So for example this would work

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double FEDERAL_TAX_PERCENT = 10.00; 
        double STATE_TAX_PERCENT = 4.5;
        double SOCIAL_SECURITY_PERCENT = 6.2;
        double MEDICARE_PERCENT = 1.45;
        double PAY_PER_HOUR = 7.25;
        
        int HoursPerWeek = 40;
        static double GrossPay = PAY_PER_HOUR * HoursPerWeek;
        
        
        double Federal = GrossPay * FEDERAL_TAX_PERCENT / 100;
        double State = GrossPay * STATE_TAX_PERCENT / 100;
        double SocialSecurity= GrossPay * SOCIAL_SECURITY_PERCENT / 100;
        double Medicare = GrossPay * MEDICARE_PERCENT / 100;
         
        double NetPay = GrossPay - Federal - State - SocialSecurity - Medicare;
        System.out.println("Gross Pay:" + GrossPay); //the question is come up here
        System.out.println("Net Pay:");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Deductions");
        System.out.println("Federal:");
        System.out.println("State:");
        System.out.println("Social Security:");
        System.out.println("Medicare:");
    }
```

Or you could create an instance of your NetPay class and pass in your variables in the constructor and then call some function within that class to calculate your Gross Pay etc.